# Synthetic proof of Euclidean geometry problem

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

**Problem:**

$\triangle{ABC}$ is such that $\angle B=\angle C=50°$. $D$ and $E$ lie on $BC$ and $AC$ respectively such that 
$\angle ABE = 30^{\circ}$ and $\angle BAD = 50°$.
Let $F$ be the intersection point  of $AD$ and $BE$.  Find $\angle BED=x$.

I am able to do this using trigonometry. But I want a synthetic proof of this which I have failed to find. I did find a couple of congruent triangles and a few tangent circles.There is even the famous $80-80-20$ triangle in the figure. Please help.

**My solution:** I apply the sine rule to $\triangle FED$ and $\triangle AFE$

$$\frac{\sin x}{FD}=\frac{\sin(100°+x)}{FE}=\frac{\sin (x+100°) \sin70°}
{AF\sin 30° }.$$

Now, using 
$$\frac{FD}{AF}=\frac{DB  \sin20°}{AB \sin 30° }$$ and 
$$\frac{DB}{AB}=\frac{\sin 50}{\sin 80}$$

I get 
$$\sin x \sin80 =\sin(x+100)\sin70\sin20 \sin 50, $$ 
and $40^{\circ}$ solves this as can be easily guessed once the above is reduced to the following: 
$$\sin(x)=8\sin(x+100)\cos(20)\cos(40)\cos(80).$$

Comment: How is point $D$ constrained?

Comment: where is $F$ situated?

Comment: @peterwhy sry, i have edited

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner sry, i have edited

Comment: how can be $$\angle{BAC}=\angle{BAD}=50^{\circ}$$?

Comment: $\angle BAC = \angle BAD = 50^\circ$, so $C= D$.

Comment: i think there is a typo?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner now i have edited....

Comment: I am trying to solve the problem but also steps away from it. Maybe what you have found (those congruent triangles and tangent circles) can be useful. Like to share more of your findings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea: let $O$ be the circumcenter of $\triangle ABE$.

It's easy to check that $\angle OAD=\angle EAD=30^\circ$, $OA=EA$, $DA=DA$, therefore triangles $AOD$ and $AED$ are equal and $\angle EDO=2\angle ADO$. But both $O$ and $D$ lies on middle perpendicular to $AB$, so $80^\circ= \angle ADB=2\angle ADO$.

Therefore $\angle ODE=80^\circ$, $OD=DE$, so $\angle OED=50^\circ$. But $\angle OEA=90^\circ-\angle BAE=10^\circ$. Finally we have $\angle BED=\angle OED-\angle OEB=50^\circ-10^\circ=40^\circ$.